# Different View depending on ContentControl (Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm binding ViewModels to ContentControls and letting Caliburn taking care of creating and binding the view. However, I would like to customize Caliburns ViewModel->View convention based on which ContentControl I'm binding to.

For example, a regular ContentControl, I want the regular View to bind (SomethingViewModel -> SomethingView). But for a certain ContentControl, I want Caliburn to fetch a View named for example SomethingViewSpecial. Is that possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Use `cal:View.Context` attached property and then name your view for the specified context like `YourNamespace.Something.ContextView` (remove "ViewModel" from your view model name, add a dot, and the value of Context property).

By that, you can even bind several views to one view model.

Example:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Toolbar" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" cal:View.Context="Toolbar" />
```

You can see working example [here](http://coproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/610e68f20ed0#src/Coproject/Coproject/Views/ToDoListsView.xaml) (from [CoProject](http://coproject.codeplex.com/) sample application, [part 9](http://baud.cz/blog/coproject-a-ria-caliburnmicro-demo-part-9)).