# Caliburn Micro, Multiple views from a single view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have an application that I am currently working on and there is a requirement to change the view based on an event occurring. This event means that the same ViewModel must be used but using a different View. I do not currently know if this is possible to do with Caliburn but I imagine it should be. the main problem I am having is the convention over configuration element of Caliburn. Example:

I have a ViewModel "MainViewModel" and it is bound to "MainView" through convention. When the event occurs I want the application to be displaying "MainView2" instead of "MainView". I can imagine there is a programmatic way of setting this but my inexperience with Caliburn is a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control which View is used for your ViewModel by setting cal:View.Context property on ContentControl that shows the view.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190137/different-view-depending-on-contentcontrol-caliburn-micro).